# Sql Group by with transpose

Tags: sql-server

i really couldn't think of the words for the title... This is something that would take me 5 mins in excel but i'm relative new to SQL.

I have a data set that come in at a device level and each customer can have a number of device types but only one of each device type.

I want to convert the data so it comes in at a customer level and has a set of columns for each device.

I guess i need to start by grouping by Customer, but after that i'm stuck.

original data

```
Customer - ID -  Device - Status - Date
1        -  1 -  A      -  open   - 01/10/2020
1        -  2 -  B      -  Closed - 02/10/2020
1        -  3 -  C      -  open   - 03/10/2020
2        -  4 -  A      -  open   - 01/10/2020
2        -  5 -  B      -  Closed - 02/10/2020
2        -  6 -  C      -  open   - 03/10/2020
```

new headers

```
Customer - Device A ID - Device A Status - Device A Date - Device B ID - Device B Status - Device B Date - Device C ID - Device C Status - Device C Date
```

does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't need a Dynamic Pivot, a conditional aggregation should do the trick

```
Select Customer
      ,[Device A ID]     = max(case when Device='A' then ID end)
      ,[Device A Status] = max(case when Device='A' then [Status] end)
      ,[Device A Date]   = max(case when Device='A' then [Date] end)
      ,[Device B ID]     = max(case when Device='B' then ID end)
      ,[Device B Status] = max(case when Device='B' then [Status] end)
      ,[Device B Date]   = max(case when Device='B' then [Date] end)
      ,[Device C ID]     = max(case when Device='C' then ID end)
      ,[Device C Status] = max(case when Device='C' then [Status] end)
      ,[Device C Date]   = max(case when Device='C' then [Date] end)
 From  YourTable
 Group By Customer
```

**Edit - Just for fun, here is a PIVOT option**

```
Select *
 From  (
        Select A.Customer
              ,B.*
         From  YourTable A
         Cross Apply ( values (concat('Device ',Device,' ID')    ,concat('',[ID]) )
                             ,(concat('Device ',Device,' Status'),concat('',[Status]) )
                             ,(concat('Device ',Device,' Date'),concat('',[Date]) )
                     ) B(Item,Value)
       ) src
 Pivot ( max(value) for Item in ( [Device A ID],[Device A Status],[Device A Date],[Device B ID],[Device B Status],[Device B Date],[Device C ID],[Device C Status],[Device C Date] ) ) pvt
```

**Returns**

[image]